# OData v4 Expanding Multiple One-Many

Tags: rest, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API using OData v4.

[I just made a GitHub repo here](https://github.com/Justin-Michiels/GGHR-Backend) containing the entire solution, even the database project with dummy data.

Some blogs helped me along the way:

[Experimenting with OData in ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/experimenting-with-odata-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)

[Supercharging ASP.NET Core API with OData](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/supercharging-asp-net-core-api-with-odata/)

I've successfully created 3 basic endpoints that can be queried (Countries, Cities and Customers).
The Country and City endpoints work as expected, it is the Customer endpoint that causes some issues on $expand.

The Customer model looks like this (please note that I am currently using domain entities instead of DTO's because I want to get everything working smoothly first, before projecting them to DTO's):

```
public abstract class AppEntity : IAppEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : AppEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual City City { get; set; }
    public string VAT { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CustomerEmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CustomerNote> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

With the following models acting as navigation properties:

```
public class CustomerEmailAddress : AppEntity
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerNote : AppEntity
{
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Most of my queries are successful:

1. Just the collection: https://localhost:44309/api/customer
2. Expanding the City: https://localhost:44309/api/customer?$expand=City
3. On of the one-many relationships: https://localhost:44309/api/customer?$expand=Notes

But as soon as I try to expand 2 or more one-many properties or expand all (?$expand=*), I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')
```

Any clue where this exception might be coming from?

My EdmModel is defined as:

```
IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Country>("Country");
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<City>("City");
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customer");

    return odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error after migrating to OData w/ .NET Core 3.1

Comment: It looks like there is an issue with EF Core on this:  https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2016 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19616 https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/19623